# how i can read file and store its containt in variable?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, files

I want to store number in file for example file `number.txt` contain `3242` I want to real this file and store its contant in variable for example variable `number_var = number.txt` so that `number_var = 3242`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
number_var=$(cat number.txt)
```

Answer (score 3):

The backtick is your friend:

```
[madhatta@risby tmp]$ cat foo
1234
[madhatta@risby tmp]$ fred=`cat foo`
[madhatta@risby tmp]$ echo $fred
1234
```

You had better be pretty sure the file is a one-liner, though; if you import the whole of /boot/vmlinuz into a shell variable, you may start putting pressure on memory!

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, ksh and zsh:

```
number_var=$(<number.txt)
```